# Objective-C. Increment with remembering previous result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

In Objective-C, I have a simple program that increments a counter each time a button is pushed.
But I need to increment previous result. 1, 2, 3, etc
Now it always increments from 0 to 1.
How to tell programm wich was the previous number?
What i have to put instead 0?

Code:

```
- (IBAction) plus;{

    int counterPlus = 0;
    counterPlus++;
    counterField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counterPlus]; 
}
```

Comment: make counterPlus an instance variable and initialize it to 0 within init. then, remove "int counterPlus = 0" from your code above.

Answer (score 4):

make `int counterPlus;` an instance variable.

```
// MONObject.h
@interface MONObject : NSObject
{
@private
  int counterPlus;
}

- (IBAction)plus;

@end

// MONObject.m
@implementation MONObject

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (0 != self) {
    counterPlus = 0;
  }
  return self;
}

- (IBAction)plus {
    counterPlus++;
    counterField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counterPlus]; 
}

@end
```

**Update**

To elaborate on Mats' response to your question:

The reason you would avoid the `static` variant is that it is a shared global variable.

That means that the one static/global variable will start at zero and increment every time `plus` is called on any instance. When you create a new button, its number in the counter field will be equal to the total number of times `plus` had been called *since your program was launched* (assuming no threading issues). With an instance variable, the count will be equal to the number of times `plus` was pressed for that instance of that button.

Global variables, as you can see from the comments, are also 'EVIL'. They are a big source of problems, and are best avoided.

Comment: Great! It works too! What's difference between using static int, like was described below?

Comment: With static you can only have one counter. It is only one variable in memory. When using this solution you can always make more counters, because you can make more object. A bettor Object Oriented and design solution.

Comment: @Vladmir updated/expanded on Mats response with examples and a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Declare counterPlus `static`. By declaring so, on successive calls to the method will remember it's previous value of counterPlus or to say the initialization takes place only once.

```
static int counterPlus = 0;
```

It's always better to have it as an instance variable, which is the correct apporoach though.

Comment: PLEASE Note that this variable will be shared by all instances of the class this is used in. `static` is a globally 'shared' variable for that class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make that int static, so that it retains value from call to call.

Comment: noooooo static variables are EVIL. do NOT use them to store state, especially in cases where an instance variable does the job.